# mpirun --cpu-set vs. --rankfile (Open MPI) 1.4.5

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, pinning, likwid

I want to accurately pin my MPI processes to a list of (physical) cores. I refer to the following points of the mpirun --help output:

```
   -cpu-set|--cpu-set <arg0>  
                         Comma-separated list of ranges specifying logical
                         cpus allocated to this job [default: none]
```

...

```
   -rf|--rankfile <arg0>  
                         Provide a rankfile file
```

The topology of my processor is as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
CPU type:       Intel Core Bloomfield processor 
*************************************************************
Hardware Thread Topology
*************************************************************
Sockets:        1 
Cores per socket:       4 
Threads per core:       2 
-------------------------------------------------------------
HWThread        Thread          Core            Socket
0               0               0               0
1               0               1               0
2               0               2               0
3               0               3               0
4               1               0               0
5               1               1               0
6               1               2               0
7               1               3               0
-------------------------------------------------------------
Socket 0: ( 0 4 1 5 2 6 3 7 )
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, if I start my programm using **mpirun -np 2 --cpu-set 0,1 --report-bindings ./solver** the program starts normally but without considering the **--cpu-set** argument I provided. On the other hand starting my program with **mpirun -np 2 --rankfile rankfile --report-bindings ./solver** gives me the following output:

```
[neptun:14781] [[16333,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[16333,1],0] to slot_list 0
[neptun:14781] [[16333,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[16333,1],1] to slot_list 1
```

Indeed checking with **top** shows me that mpirun actually uses the specified cores. But how should I interpret this output? Except for the host (*neptun*) and the specified slots (*0,1*) I don't have a clue. Same with the other commands I tried out:

```
$mpirun --np 2 --bind-to-core --report-bindings ./solver
[neptun:15166] [[15694,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[15694,1],0] to cpus 0001
[neptun:15166] [[15694,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[15694,1],1] to cpus 0002
```

and

```
$mpirun --np 2 --bind-to-socket --report-bindings ./solver
[neptun:15188] [[15652,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[15652,1],0] to socket 0 cpus 000f
[neptun:15188] [[15652,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[15652,1],1] to socket 0 cpus 000f
```

With **--bind-to-core**, the **top** command once again shows me that cores 0 and 1 are used, but why is the output **cpus 0001** and **0002**? **--bind-to-socket** causes even more confusion: 2x **000f**?

I use the last paragraph to summarize the questions that arose from my experiments:

- Why isn't my **--cpu-set** command working?
- How am I supposed to interpret the output resulting from the **--report-bindings** output?

**References**
The CPU-Topology was read out using [LIKWID Performance Tools](https://hpc.fau.de/research/tools/likwid/), more precisely using [`likwid-topology`](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid/wiki/likwid-topology).
LIKWID is licensed under the GPL-3.0 license, see their [GitHub](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid) for more info.

Comment: How did you get the hardware topology?

Comment: @apadana good question. I'll have to do some research and add it to my post, but maybe this post already gives you what you're looking for

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26763132/2457256

Comment: @apadana Back in the time (notice that my post is from 2013) I used LIKWID Performance Tools https://hpc.fau.de/research/tools/likwid/
I'll update my post shortly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both cases the output matches exactly what you have told Open MPI to do. The hexadecimal number in `cpus ...` shows the allowed CPUs (the affinity mask) for the process. This is a bit field with each bit representing one logical CPU.

With `--bind-to-core` each MPI process is bound to its own CPU core. Rank 0 (`[...,0]`) has its affinity mask set to `0001` which means logical CPU 0. Rank 1 (`[...,1]`) has its affinity mask set to `0002` which means logical CPU 1. The logical CPU numbering probably matches the `HWThread` identifier in the output with the topology information.

With `--bind-to-socket` each MPI process is bound to all cores of the socket. In your particular case the affinity mask is set to `000f`, or `0000000000001111` in binary, which corresponds to all four cores in the socket. Only a single hyperthread per core is being assigned.

You can further instruct Open MPI how to select the sockets on multisocket nodes. With `--bysocket` the sockets are selected in round-robin fashion, i.e. the first rank is placed on the first socket, the next rank is placed on the next socket, and so on until there is one process per socket, then the next rank is again put on the first socket and so on. With `--bycore` each sockets receives as much consecutive ranks as is the number of cores in that socket.

I would suggest that you read the manual for `mpirun` for Open MPI 1.4.x, especially the [Process Binding](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect9) section. There are some examples there with how the different binding options interact with each other. The `--cpu-set` option is not mentioned in the manual, although Jeff Squyres has written a nice page on [processor affinity features in Open MPI](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/open-mpi-v1-5-processor-affinity-options/) (it is about v1.5, but most if not all of it applies to v1.4 also).

Comment: That solves the problem, thank you! Nice links, I already had spent a lot of time on those two pages, but I couldn't find an explanation for the not working cpu-set option...

Comment: @Zboson, for some reason I've given a link to the German mirror of Open MPI, which is gone. Fixed.