# How do I find my CPU topology?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-architecture

I am using Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M 560 @ 2.67GHz as I found out from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. But I want to know exact hierarchy like how many sockets are there, and how many cores are there per socket and threads too, if supported. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use command

> **lscpu**

this will give information

for processor related info

> **dmidecode -t processor**

Answer (score 24):

`lstopo` from the `hwloc` package reports the info you want:

> ```
> Socket L#0 + L3 L#0 (6144KB)
>   L2 L#0 (256KB) + L1 L#0 (32KB) + Core L#0
>     PU L#0 (P#0)
>     PU L#1 (P#1)
>   L2 L#1 (256KB) + L1 L#1 (32KB) + Core L#1
>     PU L#2 (P#2)
>     PU L#3 (P#3)
>   L2 L#2 (256KB) + L1 L#2 (32KB) + Core L#2
>     PU L#4 (P#4)
>     PU L#5 (P#5)
>   L2 L#3 (256KB) + L1 L#3 (32KB) + Core L#3
>     PU L#6 (P#6)
>     PU L#7 (P#7)
> ```

Comment: And running lstopo in a graphical environment gives an easy to understand graphical output, even for more complex topologies

Comment: If only console output is possible (e.g. ssh and no X forward) use `lstopo --of ascii`. Particularly useful in WSL.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `likwid-topology -g` to get cpu hierarchy. This is not available by default in linux, you can install in ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install likwid`

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the `core id` and `cpu cores` values in `/proc/cpuinfo`. They should provide the values you need.

Alternatively, look at the [specifications page](http://ark.intel.com/products/49653/) of your processor.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106887/2457256

On your Linux machine, you can install [LIKWID Performance Tools](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid), where you'll find the command line tool `likwid-topology`. See their [README](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid#download-build-and-install) for a quick installation guide.

You  can use LIKWID to generate plots directly from your command line like this one (taken from the LIKWID Documentation)

```
CPU name:   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz
CPU type:   Intel Kabylake processor
CPU stepping:   10
********************************************************************************
Hardware Thread Topology
********************************************************************************
Sockets:        1
Cores per socket:   4
Threads per core:   2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HWThread        Thread        Core        Die        Socket        Available
0               0             0           0          0             *                
1               0             1           0          0             *                
2               0             2           0          0             *                
3               0             3           0          0             *                
4               1             0           0          0             *                
5               1             1           0          0             *                
6               1             2           0          0             *                
7               1             3           0          0             *                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Socket 0:       ( 0 4 1 5 2 6 3 7 )
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
********************************************************************************
Cache Topology
********************************************************************************
Level:          1
Size:           32 kB
Cache groups:       ( 0 4 ) ( 1 5 ) ( 2 6 ) ( 3 7 )
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level:          2
Size:           256 kB
Cache groups:       ( 0 4 ) ( 1 5 ) ( 2 6 ) ( 3 7 )
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Level:          3
Size:           6 MB
Cache groups:       ( 0 4 1 5 2 6 3 7 )
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
********************************************************************************
NUMA Topology
********************************************************************************
NUMA domains:       1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Domain:         0
Processors:     ( 0 4 1 5 2 6 3 7 )
Distances:      10
Free memory:        4303.62 MB
Total memory:       7829.29 MB
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

See [`likwid-topology`](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid/wiki/likwid-topology) for more information on the command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain this info by
`lscpu` and  `nproc` all other is in `/proc/cpuinfo`